# Как при Access Violation в Delphi, остановить на строке с ошибкой?

Tags: delphi

Собственно вопрос в заголовке? Я вроде выставлял галочки в настройках по инструкции, давно правда.

**upd**

[image: общие настройки дебагера][image: настройки проэкта]

Comment: Options - Debugger - Break on Exception

Comment: нет у меня такого, и похожего, вроде просмотрел все. Delphi XE8

Comment: Главное условие - делать Debug Build и тогда, с настройками по умолчанию, Delphi сама остановится на нужной строке.

Comment: Запускал проект без дебагера Ctrl+F9 вместо F9, поэтому и не останавливалось на ошибке

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Должны быть опции отладки в компиляторе включены для проекта (Project - Options). То есть добавлены отладочные маркеры в код. После этого build надо делать, чтобы они добавились.
И еще если есть опция "Optimization", то её тоже нужно отключить. И сделать Build проекта.

Comment: "Optimization" отключён

Comment: просто отладчик по F7-F8 переходит по строкам.F4 работает? Контрольные точки?